# Objective-C OpenGL how to rotate, scale

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have the following source code where i can draw some objects to the screen but i want to rotate and scale the drawed object and nothing happens when i am touching the screen. (In the log i can see if i am doing a pan gesture or a pinch gesture so the detection is ok)

What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Now it moves (instead of rotation) maybe i rotate it not around the center of the pointcloud. I tried to move it to center but now nothing is on the screen.  Here is the updated Code:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <OpenGLES/EAGLDrawable.h>

#import "EAGLView.h"
#import "VertexPoint.h"
#import "CamOnMap-Swift.h"
#import <Math.h>

#define USE_DEPTH_BUFFER 1
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(__ANGLE) ((__ANGLE) / 180.0 * M_PI)

// A class extension to declare private methods
@interface EAGLView ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) EAGLContext *context;
//@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimer *animationTimer;

- (BOOL) createFramebuffer;
- (void) destroyFramebuffer;

@end


@implementation EAGLView

@synthesize context;
//@synthesize animationTimer;
//@synthesize animationInterval;


// You must implement this method
+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    NSLog(@"Ide eljutottam ez az initWithCoder");
    TOUCH_ROT_FACTOR = (180.0 / 320.0);
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        // Get the layer
        CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;

        eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
        eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];

        context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

        if (!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context]) {
            //[self release];
            return nil;
        }

        // animationInterval = 1.0 / 60.0;
        [self setupView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setupView {
    const GLfloat zNear = 0.1, zFar = 1000.0, fieldOfView = 60.0;
    GLfloat size;

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    size = zNear * tanf(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(fieldOfView) / 2.0);

    //Grab the size of the screen
    CGRect rect = self.frame;
    glFrustumf(-size, size,
               -size / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height),
               size / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height),
               zNear, zFar);
    glViewport(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    //Initialize touchLocation to 0, 0
   // touchLocation = CGPointMake(rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2);

   // touchLocation = CGPointMake(0, 0);
   // GLfloat x = (touchLocation.x);
   // GLfloat y = (touchLocation.y);
    //translate the triangle
   //  glTranslatef(x, y, -10.0);
    multitouch_distance_start = 0;
    viewDistance = -100;
    [self setupGestures];
    [self getPly];

}

- (void)setupGestures{
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:true];
    [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:true];

    pinchGesture =  [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchHandler:)];
    panGesture =[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panHandler:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

};
-(VertexPoint*)center:(NSMutableArray *)vertices2{

    float sum_x =0.0f;
     float sum_y =0.0f;
     float sum_z =0.0f;
    for (int i=0; i<vertices2.count; i++) {

       VertexPoint *point =vertices2[i];

        sum_x +=point.x;
        sum_y +=point.y;
        sum_z +=point.z;
    }

      center_ = [[VertexPoint alloc] init];
    GLfloat point[] = {(sum_x / vertices2.count),(sum_y / vertices2.count), (sum_z / vertices2.count)};
    [center_ setPosition:point];
    return center_;

}
-(float)multiTouchDistance:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) recognizer{
    float x1 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self].x;
    float y1 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self].y;
    float x2 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:1 inView:self].x;
    float y2 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:1 inView:self].y;
    float dx = x2 - x1;
    float dy = y2 - y1;
    return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}

- (void)pinchHandler:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    glPopMatrix();
    float d = [self multiTouchDistance:recognizer];
    NSLog(@"d: %f",d);

    if(d > 0.0f)multitouch_distance_start = d;
    viewDistance *= multitouch_distance_start / d;
    multitouch_distance_start = d;
    //glScalef(recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    //recognizer.scale = 1;
    NSLog(@"viewDistance: %f",viewDistance);
    glPushMatrix();

    [self render];
}

- (void)panHandler:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
        xPrev = translation.x;
        yPrev = translation.y;
    }
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){
        glPopMatrix();

        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
        GLfloat dx = translation.x - xPrev;
        GLfloat dy = translation.y - yPrev;

        xAngle +=  ((dx) * (TOUCH_ROT_FACTOR));
        yAngle +=  ((dy) * (TOUCH_ROT_FACTOR));

       // glRotatef(xAngle,1,0,0);
       // glRotatef(yAngle,0,1,0);

        xPrev = translation.x;
        yPrev = translation.y;

        glPushMatrix();
        NSLog(@"pan");
        [self render];
    }

};

-(void)completionHandler:(NSString *) data{
   // NSLog(@"%@",data);
    NSArray *dataArray = [data componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    vertices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(NSInteger i = 14; i < dataArray.count; i++ ){
        NSArray *row = [dataArray[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        if(![dataArray[i]  isEqual: @""]){

        VertexPoint *point = [[VertexPoint alloc] init];
            GLfloat a[] = { [[row objectAtIndex:0] floatValue], [[row objectAtIndex:1] floatValue], [[row objectAtIndex:2] floatValue]};
        [point setPosition:a];
        GLfloat b[] = { [[row objectAtIndex:6] floatValue],[[row objectAtIndex:7] floatValue], [[row objectAtIndex:8] floatValue],  [[row objectAtIndex:9] floatValue]};
        [point setColor:b];
            [vertices addObject:point];
        }
    }
    long vcount = [vertices count] * 3; // * 2 for the two coordinates of a loc object

    glVertices = (GLfloat *)malloc(vcount * sizeof(GLfloat));
    int currIndex = 0;
    for (VertexPoint *loc in vertices) {
        glVertices[currIndex++] = (loc.x);
        glVertices[currIndex++] =(loc.y);
        glVertices[currIndex++] =(loc.z);
    }
    long ccount = [vertices count] * 4;
    glColors = (GLfloat *)malloc(ccount * sizeof(GLfloat));
    int currColorIndex = 0;
    for(VertexPoint *color in vertices){
        glColors[currColorIndex++] = (color.r);
        glColors[currColorIndex++] = (color.g);
        glColors[currColorIndex++] = (color.b);
        glColors[currColorIndex++] = (color.a);
    }
    center_ = [self center: vertices];

    glTranslatef(0, 0, -100);

  //  glTranslatef(-1 * center_.x, -1 * center_.y, -1 * center_.z);
    NSLog(@"x: %f, y: %f, z:%f",-1 * center_.x,-1 * center_.y,-1 * center_.z);
    [self drawView];


};
-(void)getPly{

    GlobalDataFunctions *globalDataFunctions = [[GlobalDataFunctions alloc] init];
    NSString *ply = [globalDataFunctions selectedPly];
    NSLog(@"%@",ply);
    RestClient *restClient = [[RestClient alloc] init];
    NSString *username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"];
    NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"password"];
    [restClient getPly: username password:password ply:ply myComletionHandler: ^(NSString *data){
        [self completionHandler:data];
    }];

};

- (void)drawView {
    NSLog(@"drawView");

    //setting up the draw content
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);

    //Draw stuff

    //reset matrix to identity
    glLoadIdentity();
    //rough approximation of screen to current 3D space
    GLfloat x = (touchLocation.x - 160.0) / 38.0;
    GLfloat y = (240.0 - touchLocation.y) / 38.0;
    //translate the triangle
    glTranslatef(x, y, -1.0);

    [self render];

}

-(void)render{
    NSLog(@"render");

    center_ = [self center: vertices];

   // glTranslatef(-1 * center_.x, -1 * center_.y, -1 * center_.z);

    //clear the back color back to our original color and depth buffer
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //rough approximation of screen to current 3D space

    //set the format and location for verticies
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, glVertices);
    //set the opengl state
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    //set the format and location for colors
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, glColors);
    //set the opengl state
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glPointSize(3);
    //draw the triangles
   // glTranslatef(0,0,viewDistance);
   // glTranslatef(-1 * center_.x, -1 * center_.y, -1 * center_.z);
      glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertices.count);

    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
    //show the render buffer
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];

}

 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
 touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
    NSLog(@"touch");
      [self drawView];
 }

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    [self destroyFramebuffer];
    [self createFramebuffer];
     [self drawView];
}


- (BOOL)createFramebuffer {

    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

    if (USE_DEPTH_BUFFER) {
        glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
        glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
        glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
        glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
    }

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) {
        NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}


- (void)destroyFramebuffer {

    glDeleteFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
    viewFramebuffer = 0;
    glDeleteRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
    viewRenderbuffer = 0;

    if(depthRenderbuffer) {
        glDeleteRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
        depthRenderbuffer = 0;
    }
}
```

And here can you find a sample input data: http://pastebin.com/rcrfZdyt

Comment: In the pan handler, you are pushing the current modelview matrix to the stack, modify it, and overwrite the modification by poping the matrix from the stack again. You are also resetting your modelview  matrix to identity in `drawView()`.

Comment: Thanks it was good but now i have other problems. I updated my post